# Angular App Login Authentication using user name & password only and check the associated tenant from the backend layer

Tags: cumulocity

We are developing an angular 6 App for showing the sensor data and other details.

In this app, we are having the login screen, in that we have only the USERNAME & PASSWORD fields.

once we enter the Username & Password, the request will go to the BACK-END Layer (.net ) controller logic, which in-turn contacts the Adamos / Cumulocity Platform and get the associated tenant and return the authorization token to the front end, which will gets saved in the Local Storage or Session storage.

From the above details, i wanted to know what are the things possible

1. Can we contact the cumulocity / Adamos from the .net back end layer and find out the associated tenant for the given username & password ?
2. Can we create & return the custom User Object & with user permission, token for login authorization checkings ?
3. If we want to store the jwt token, where we have to store the token?

Note: 
We know that we can directly contact the Adamos / cumulocity to authorize the user using the tenant, username and password, but don't want the user to enter their tenant, instead directly using the corporate user id & password only, which has been registered in the adamos environment.

Please give us details information, as we are developing an complicated application, so that there won't be any problem with the core design.

Thank you
PCAPA B.

Comment: I am bit confused about the JWT part .. where does this come from? Do you want to use the OAuth feature in 9.12+?

Comment: Yes you can consider it is OAuth.

Comment: Any one from cumulocity team, please answer my clarification, we are blocked here. Sorry for asking again

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the current state of adamos, but that should not be possible in the cumulocity platform. You need the tenant to authenticate there as there theoretically could be duplicate user names across tenants.

Comment: Yes we require the tenant, but will it be possible to find out the tenant using the username and password only, by again sending some request to adamos from the backend layer (may be .net) to find the related tenant and send the control back to the brower to move the next screen ?

Comment: I don't think such an endpoint exists.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot determine the tenant from a username and a password. Each tenant has their own user domain with their own users. If you have a user in a tenant with global user read permission, you can query the users in the tenant. You can also the query the permissions.

In case you are using OAuth, you do not handle the JWT token, at least in a web application. The token is managed by the browser in a cookie. This is transparent for you and the cookie is not accessible from your (JavaScript) application code. If you use a "fat" client or microservice, you would need to emulate that logic (i.e., passing the cookie around).

I am not sure if that really answers your question. If not, please be a bit more specific.